# CPU stats were not captured for docker containers

Tags: virtualization, docker, openstack

I am newbie to docker and I have started my docker containers and I am not able to see the cpu/memory stats being written to the files in cgroup system slice files. Please have a look at the snapshot below

[root@docker docker-5ae16d70ee83102b0a8a65adc4468a9251e22ed8b8916e786564869da2b09524.scope]# ls -rlt
total 0

-r--r--r--. 1 root root 0 Aug  6 03:19 cpu.stat

Am I missing something here? Do I need to change anything to get the performance stats of containers